# How to make Devise authentication respond to JSON only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

How to disable in Devise handling of HTML and XML requests and leave JSON only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I imagine you could override the Devise Controllers:

In `controllers/devise_overrides/sessions_controller.rb`:

```
class DeviseOverrides::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  respond_to :json
  respond_to :html, only: []
  respond_to :xml, only: []

end
```

In `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions:  "devise_overrides/sessions"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must `clear_respond_to` (for clear all types previously defined, like HTML or XML) and then `respond_to :json` in the override controller...

**config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users , controllers: {
  sessions: 'users/sessions',
  registrations: 'users/registrations'
}
```

**controllers/users/sessions**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    clear_respond_to 
    respond_to :json
end
```

**controllers/users/registrations**

```
class Users::/RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    clear_respond_to 
    respond_to :json
end
```

It works in Rails 5.2 for me!

Answer (score 1):

```rb
module DeviseOverrides
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    # Respond only to JSON calls
    clear_respond_to
    respond_to :json
  end
end
```